# How can I SELECT MIN(pret) having 2 different currencies?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Produs
(
    model NUMBER NOT NULL,
    fabricant VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    categorie VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    pret NUMBER NOT NULL
);
```

I have table `Produs`, where `pret` represents the price and `moneda` represents the currency which is `'RON'` or `'EUR'`. I have to select the model, fabricant (manufacturer in English) for the minimum price.

The problem is that I didn't know how to convert `EUR` to `RON`, and this is what I've written:

```
FROM Produs
WHERE pret < (SELECT MIN(pret) FROM produs WHERE pret=(
CASE
WHEN moneda='RON' THEN pret
WHEN moneda='EUR' THEN pret*5
ELSE pret
END) )
```

It works but shows me a lot of rows.

Comment: Your Create Table demo above does not have a moneda column.  Was 'model' supposed to be 'moneda'.  Maybe edit your question to show it?

Comment: "The problem is that I didn't know how to convert EUR to RON" That is a currency conversion problem and depends on the exchange rate at a given date and is not something that can be easily solved without having a source of the current exchange rate.

Comment: Sorry mate, I forgot to say that table was updated with a new column named moneda. About the exchange rate, things are not so complicated.... 1EUR=5RON.      Hope this helps

Comment: model is instead of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is finding any rows where the `pret` value is less than the minimum value, using a comparison which will essentially exclude any EUR value unless there happens to be a row with a matching RON (x 5); so depending on the exact data you're doing to get the lowest RON value, and find any (unadjusted) values lower than that, which will all be EUR. Or if the lowest `pret` happens to be in RON, it won't find anything.

If you wanted all the columns, including the adjusted price, and you're on a fairly recent version of Oracle, you could do:

```
SELECT model, fabricant, categorie, moneda, pret,
  CASE moneda WHEN 'EUR' THEN pret * 5 ELSE pret END as adj_pret
FROM produs
ORDER BY adj_pret
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

or if you just want the `model` and `fabricant` (or any other original values, but not the adjust value) then:

```
SELECT model, fabricant
FROM produs
ORDER BY CASE moneda WHEN 'EUR' THEN pret * 5 ELSE pret END
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TOX0nTtb)

On older versions which don't support `FETCH` you can use a subquery and `rownum` or a ranking function to achieve the same thing.

If there are multiple rows with the same adjusted value then which you will see is indeterminate. You can either change `ONLY` to `WITH TIES` to show all of them, or add to the `ORDER BY` clause to make the result determinate - e.g. `ORDER BY adj_pret, model` to get whichever of the rows has the lowest ID.

---

> I must use MIN()

You could get the minimum adjusted value in a subquery, which is sort of what you were attempting I think; but then you have to compare the adjusted value of each row with that too:

```
SELECT model, fabricant
FROM produs
WHERE CASE moneda WHEN 'EUR' THEN pret * 5 ELSE pret END = (
  SELECT MIN(CASE moneda WHEN 'EUR' THEN pret * 5 ELSE pret END)
  FROM produs
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mbBxJ-1h)

That has the opposite default behaviour - if there are multiple rows with the same adjusted value then it will show them all, like `WITH TIES`. If you only ever want a single result then you'll need to add an order-by clause to and `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` to get a determinate result.

Comment: one more thing I forgot to mention is that I must use MIN(). Is there any chance you can help me?

Comment: Why must you use `min()`? It isn't necessary to achieve the result.

Comment: This is how the requirement of the problem is formulated.